# wxpython create toolbar with calling other class

Tags: python, class, wxpython, toolbar

I'am trying to make a toolbar in wx python. I can make it in my main file, but I am using many .py files to make the programming more clear.

In my main file I have this code:

```
from microanalysis_menubar_view import TBar as toolbar_view

class Main(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.SetTitle('Microanalysis')

        # add menubar
        self.menubar = menubar_view()
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)

        #add toolbar
        self.toolbar = toolbar_view()
```

In my other file (microanalysis_menubar_view) I have this:

```
class TBar(wx.ToolBar):

    def __init__(self):

        wx.ToolBar.__init__(self)

        toolbar = self.CreateToolBar()
        qtool = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Quit', wx.Bitmap('exit.png'))
        toolbar.Realize()
```

And I get this error:

TypeError: Required argument 'parent' (pos 1) not found

I had also problems with adding a menubar this way, but I solved that. This is more difficult.

I tried switching 'toolbar.Realize() to my main file:

```
self.toolbar.Realize(self.toolbar)
```

That doesn't work either.
Tx in advance

Answer (score 0):

The wx.ToolBar object needs a parent as first argument. You do not provide that.

If you want to create your toolbar you need to add the parent object. So your call to create the toolbar **init** function would start like this:

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    wx.ToolBar.__init__(self, parent)
```

To create the toolbar itself you need to call

```
#add toolbar
self.toolbar = toolbar_view(self)
```

This way you hand over yourself as parent argument and you provide this to the wx.ToolBar object as parent.

Hope this helps.
Michael

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think it helped, but I can't test it because now I've got another error: AttributeError: 'TBar' object has no attribute 'CreateToolBar' . I think I cannot use 'createToolBar' in a self-defined class?

Comment: CreateToolBar is a frame method to create a standard toolbar. Use the frames SetToolBar method to add your user defined instance of toolbar to the frame.